# Simple left join in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Private-Message Table and a User-Table.

I connect them here:

```
 var messageUsers = (from pm in dc.PrivateMessages
                                join user in dc.Users
                                on pm.SenderID equals user.UserID
                                where !pm.IsDeletedRecipient && pm.RecipientID == id
                                select new PMInbox
                                {
                                    SenderUsername = user.Username,
                                    PrivateMessageID = pm.PrivateMessageID,
                                    SenderID = pm.SenderID,
                                    Subject = pm.Subject,
                                    Text = pm.Text,
                                    SenderType = pm.SenderType,
                                    IsDeletedRecipient = pm.IsDeletedRecipient,
                                    IsDeletedSender = pm.IsDeletedSender,
                                    IsRead = pm.IsRead,
                                    Timestamp = pm.TimestampSend

                                }).ToList();
```

How to make this in a left-join, so if the userID is not the SenderID (e.g. The Sender is deleted allready), the Username should be empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var messageUsers = (
      from pm in dc.PrivateMessages
      where !pm.IsDeletedRecipient && pm.RecipientID == id
      select new PMInbox {
          SenderUsername = (
                from user in dc.Users
                where user.UserID == pm.SenderID
                select user.Username
              ).SingleOrDefault(),
          PrivateMessageID = pm.PrivateMessageID,
          //...
      }
    ).ToList();
```

In general, to achieve a Left outer join in LINQ, you should be using `SingleOrDefault` or possibly `FirstOrDefault` when you wish to include 1 or 0 rows of the joined "table", and `DefaultIfEmpty` when you may need to include *several* lines (in my experience, that's a less common occasion, however).  In your specific case, it sounds like `UserID` is a unique identifier for `Users` - as such, I translated your left join into a `SingleOrDefault` call rather than a `DefaultIfEmpty` call.

Unlike SQL, .NET cannot resolve properties on null values.  So if you do something like `user.Username` and `user` is null, you'll get a `NullReferenceException`.  You can then either check for null every single time you access `user`, or you can project (i.e. `select`) *before* calling `SingleOrDefault` or `DefaultIfEmpty`.  After all, an *empty* sequence of users selects an *empty* sequence of usernames - which, after `SingleOrDefault` creates a name or `null` without the need for any manual `null`-checking.

Answer (score 1):

Do a group join, then unpack the group by querying it.  The DefaultIfEmpty generates a null element when the collection is empty.

```
var messageUsers = (
  from pm in dc.PrivateMessages
  join u in dc.Users 
    on pm.SenderID equals u.UserID
    into users 
  from user in users.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where !pm.IsDeletedRecipient && pm.RecipientID == id 
...
```

Also, if you have Associations set up between the tables in the dbml, there should be a relational property from PrivateMessage to User that can be used to express the query more simply.  (I'm naming that property Senders, but it might be auto-named Users or Users1.  You can rename the property in the dbml.)

```
var messageUsers = (
   from pm in dc.PrivateMessages
   where !pm.IsDeletedRecipient && pm.RecipientID == id
   from user in pm.Senders.DefaultIfEmpty()
   ...
```

Comment: Didn't work: Error 40 The name 'user' is not in scope on the right side of 'equals'.  Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'. O:\Flirt4Date\Flirt4Date\DAL\PrivateMessageHandling.cs 79 63 DAL